# MariaDB multiple auth modules for a user?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, authentication, password

[MariaDB has pluggable authentication,](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/development-pluggable-authentication/) like PostgreSQL. Unlike PostgreSQL, I can't figure out how to support two forms of auth for a user. For instance, in PostgreSQL we can have the following in our [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             all                     md5
local   all             all                                     peer
```

This permits

1. all users to connect using password auth
2. all users that are local to connect using the [peer method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html)

How do I make it so all local users can connect over Unix sockets if they're authenticated with the operating system, and with a password in the event one is set in the database?

MariaDB provides

- `mysql_native_password`
- `unix_socket`

It seems the mysql.user only supports one "plugin"

```
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT user,host,plugin FROM user;
+------+-----------+-------------+
| user | host      | plugin      |
+------+-----------+-------------+
| root | localhost | unix_socket |
+------+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, a given user can only support one plugin. It is described in more details in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pluggable-authentication.html).